# DX11 geometry shader треугольники с дополнением

Tags: directx, шейдеры

Не могу до конца понять, как работает шейдер геометрии в DX11 при топологии с дополнительными вершинами. 
Я его понимаю так, что на вход подается 3 основных вершины и 3 дополнительных, причем последние в дальнейшем не считаются пройденными и далее сами будут отправлены как основные.
Но у меня по каким то причинам отображается лишь половина полигонов.
Использую топологию:

```
context->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST_ADJ);
```

шейдер:

```
   // Буфер констант, в котором хранятся четыре базовые матрицы в порядке по столбцам для составления геометрии.
cbuffer ModelViewProjectionConstantBuffer
{
    matrix model; // не используется
    matrix world;
    matrix view;
    matrix projection;
};

struct GeometryInputType
{
    float3 position : POSITION;
};

struct PixelShaderInput {
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 normal : NORMAL;
};

[maxvertexcount(3)]
void main(triangleadj GeometryInputType vertex[6], inout TriangleStream<PixelShaderInput> output) {

PixelShaderInput v[3];

//расчет нормали
//triangleadj состоит из 4 треугольников. Найдем нормали каждого полигона\плоскости.
float4 normalCentr;
normalCentr.xyz = cross(
    vertex[2].position.xyz - vertex[0].position.xyz,
    vertex[4].position.xyz - vertex[0].position.xyz
);
normalCentr.w = 0.0f;
float4 normal1;
normal1.xyz = cross(
    vertex[2].position.xyz - vertex[0].position.xyz,
    vertex[1].position.xyz - vertex[0].position.xyz
);
normal1.w = 0.0f;
float4 normal2;
normal2.xyz = cross(
    vertex[3].position.xyz - vertex[2].position.xyz,
    vertex[4].position.xyz - vertex[2].position.xyz
);
normal2.w = 0.0f;
float4 normal3;
normal3.xyz = cross(
    vertex[5].position.xyz - vertex[4].position.xyz,
    vertex[0].position.xyz - vertex[4].position.xyz
);
normal3.w = 0.0f;

//Теперь найдем интерполированные нормали для каждой вершины
v[0].normal = normalize((normalCentr + normal1 + normal3) / 3);
v[1].normal = normalize((normalCentr + normal2 + normal1) / 3);
v[2].normal = normalize((normalCentr + normal3 + normal2) / 3);

//преобразование позиции вершин
v[0].position = float4(vertex[0].position, 1.0f);
v[0].position = mul(v[0].position, world);
v[0].position = mul(v[0].position, view);
v[0].position = mul(v[0].position, projection);
v[1].position = float4(vertex[2].position, 1.0f);
v[1].position = mul(v[1].position, world);
v[1].position = mul(v[1].position, view);
v[1].position = mul(v[1].position, projection);
v[2].position = float4(vertex[4].position, 1.0f);
v[2].position = mul(v[2].position, world);
v[2].position = mul(v[2].position, view);
v[2].position = mul(v[2].position, projection);

output.Append(v[0]);
output.Append(v[1]);
output.Append(v[2]);
output.RestartStrip();
}
```

p.s. На оф сайте мс есть картинка, которая описывает номер каждой вершины в массиве:
[image: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-geometry-shader]

Я полагался на нее.

Comment: я не вчитывался в код, а все треугольники рисуются в одном направлении?

Comment: да. Я проверял.

Comment: Вроде как все правильно. Приведите примеры входных, выходных и ожидаемых выходных данных.

Comment: Спасибо, я уже разобрался)
Была ошибка именно во входных данных. Я рассчитывал, что GPU аппаратно "отыщет" adj вершины, но в действительности их нужно подготовить заранее на стадии приложения.